# Multipage listings with minted and captions

Tags: listings, captions, minted

I have source long listings (2+ pages) that I highlight using minited via \inputminted.  I wish to have have a caption and a reference label for the listing in \listoflistings and in my text when I refer to my code.

I have tried the attached code by I get a warning.

Package caption Warning: The option `hypcap=true' will be ignored for this
(caption)                particular \caption on input line 11.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.

Could someone explain the correct was to do this?  I do this in 13 places so I would like to understand is this the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Stuart

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}  % I use XeLaTeX to pdf with hyperlinks
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{subcaption}  %Include this in MVE as I have figures with subcaption elsewhere

\begin{document}
\listoflistings
\newpage
In my Listing~\ref{label-to-long-listing} I have more than 2 page source code listing.
\inputminted[linenos, breaklines=true,fontsize=\scriptsize, numberblanklines=false]{bash}{long.txt}
\captionof{listing}{Long Listing ToC\label{label-to-long-listing}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: "See the caption package documentation for explanation." is not an option? All package errors and warning are explained in detail, see appendix A.3 "Warnings".

Answer (score 2):

`minted` provides `listing` environment that puts the code block in a floating environment. Inside `listing` you can provide a `\caption` and a `\label`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}  % I use XeLaTeX to pdf with hyperlinks
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{subcaption}  %Include this in MVE as I have figures with subcaption elsewhere

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{long.txt}
  #!/bin/sh
  /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -o
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\listoflistings
\cleardoublepage
In my Listing~\ref{label-to-long-listing} I have more than 2 page source code listing.
\begin{listing}[H]
\inputminted[linenos, breaklines=true,fontsize=\scriptsize, numberblanklines=false]{bash}{long.txt}
\caption{Long Listing ToC\label{label-to-long-listing}}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternative is (since you want page breaks) to use

```
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
```

Also use `\captionof` inside a group as it demands so.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}  % I use XeLaTeX to pdf with hyperlinks
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}    %% use after hyperref
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{subcaption}  %Include this in MVE as I have figures with subcaption elsewhere

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{long.txt}
  #!/bin/sh
  /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -o
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\listoflistings
\cleardoublepage
In my Listing~\ref{label-to-long-listing} I have more than 2 page source code listing.
\bgroup                    %%<<-- use this
\inputminted[linenos, breaklines=true,fontsize=\scriptsize, numberblanklines=false]{bash}{long.txt}
\captionof{listing}{Long Listing ToC\label{label-to-long-listing}}
\egroup                  %% and this

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry but this only show one page of source code listing.  My code does not goto to the second or more pages.  Could you check with more than one page of code?

Comment: @Stuie I don't have a bash code that big. Yes this won't break. I will add another option.

Comment: @Stuie Check the updated answer.